# sql sum command if many tables are related

Tags: sql

i have three table t1,t2,t3.
T1 has one primary key p1
T2 has a primary key L1 and a foreign key p1 with reference to the table T1
T3 has a primary key W1 and a foreign key L1 with reference to the table T2.

In table T2 for each P1 value correspondingly there might be many L1 values and at the same time for each L1 value there might be many W1 values in table T3.Imagine that there is a column called X in the table T3,I need the sum of values of x for corresponding L1 value in table T3.

```
                       
    ---------      ---------      ---------
    |  t1   |      |   t2  |      |  t3   |
    ---------      ---------      ---------
    |p1 (PK)| 1  * |L1 (PK)| 1  * |W1 (PK)| 
    |       | ---- |p1 (FK)| ---- |L1 (FK)|
    |       | (p1) |       | (L1) |X      |
    ---------      ---------      ---------
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It looks like everything you need is in table T3 (column `L1` and `X`) based upon your question... Please clarify...

Comment: I've added what I believe is the correct layout of the tables in poor man's ER notation.

Answer (score 1):

Your structure is not entirely clear but one of these may get you going:

```
SELECT SUM(T3.x)
FROM T1
INNER JOIN T2 on T1.P1 = T2.P1
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.L1 = T3.L1
```

or

```
SELECT SUM(x)
FROM T3
WHERE L1 IN
(SELECT L1 FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON T2.P1 = T1.P1)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Imagine that there is a column called X in the table T3,I need the sum
>   of values of x for corresponding L1 value in table T3.

This gets the SUM of X in T3, where the FK L1 is in T2:

```
SELECT SUM(X) FROM T3
WHERE L1 IN (SELECT W1 FROM T2)
```